# Is there a consistent way to enumerate days/weeks/months between two dates?

Tags: python, date

I have two `datetime` objects; a start date and an end date.  I need to enumerate the days, weeks and months between the two, inclusive.

Ideally the results would be in `datetime` form, though any compatible form is fine.  Weeks and months are represented by a date corresponding to the first day of the week/month, where Monday is the first day of a week, as in ISO-8601.  This means that the result may contain a date earlier than the start date.

For example, given 2010-11-28 to 2010-12-01, the results would be as follows:

`days: 2010-11-28, 2010-11-29, 2010-11-30, 2010-12-01`

`weeks: 2010-11-22, 2010-11-29`

`months: 2010-11-01, 2010-12-01`

I realize that the list of days is by itself straightforward, but I'd like a clean and consistent solution that uses a similar approach for all three.  It seems like the `calendar` module should be useful, but I'm not seeing a good way to use it for this purpose.

Comment: What happens when you iterate the months starting with 2011-01-31? What is the next date you would expect to receive?

Comment: If you're wondering about start-dates later than the end-date, you can just assume that start <= end; if you really want to handle it, I'd expect the results to be empty otherwise.  If your question is about dates in the future, the solution should work regardless of the current date.

Comment: It's a question about consistency. Does 2011-01-31 iterated by one month become 2011-02-28? Does that iterated again become 2011-03-28?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how that matters; this is about listing months between two dates, not iterating from a start point by a certain amount.

Comment: I recommend you get a third-party date module such as NormalDate or mxDateTime. I've used the former for many years (it's a single .py file), but the latter looks better maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
import datetime
import dateutil.rrule as drrule
import dateutil.relativedelta as drel
import pprint

def dt2d(date):
    '''
    Convert a datetime.datetime to datetime.date object
    '''
    return datetime.date(date.year,date.month,date.day)

def enumerate_dates(start,end):
    days=map(dt2d,drrule.rrule(drrule.DAILY, dtstart=start, until=end))

    # Find the Monday on or before start
    start_week=start+drel.relativedelta(weekday=drel.MO(-1))
    end_week=end+drel.relativedelta(weekday=drel.MO(-1))
    weeks=map(dt2d,drrule.rrule(drrule.WEEKLY, dtstart=start_week, until=end_week))

    # Find the first day of the month
    start_month=start.replace(day=1)
    end_month=end.replace(day=1)
    months=map(dt2d,drrule.rrule(drrule.MONTHLY, dtstart=start_month, until=end_month))
    return days,weeks,months


if __name__=='__main__':
    days,weeks,months=enumerate_dates(datetime.date(2010,11,28),
                                      datetime.date(2010,12,01))
    print('''\
days: {d}
weeks: {w}
months: {m}'''.format(d=map(str,days),w=map(str,weeks),m=map(str,months)))
```

yields

```
days: ['2010-11-28', '2010-11-29', '2010-11-30', '2010-12-01']
weeks: ['2010-11-22', '2010-11-29']
months: ['2010-11-01', '2010-12-01']
```